# Docker repository name must be lowercase

Tags: docker

When trying to run the following command, I'm getting this error

> docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.

Command:

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/tmp/workdir --entrypoint /usr/local/bin/ffprobe jrottenberg/ffmpeg INPUTFILE
```

Comment: Try it with `"$PWD":/tmp/workdir` instead.

Comment: @n8te that seems to have worked.  But why am I just getting this error now?  I've used that command for months with no issue.